# Segmentation violation (SIGSEGV) when loading a Keras/Tensorflow model thats uses a Lambda layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I create a model like this and save the model:

```
def extract_and_duplicate(tensor, reps=1, batch_size=0, sample_size=0):
    tensor = K.reshape(tensor[:,:,0],(batch_size, sample_size, 1))
    if reps > 1:
        tensor = Concatenate()([tensor for i in range(reps)])
    return tensor

input = Input(batch_shape = (batch_size, sample_size, num_features))
out = <steps to create a NN with several layers>

pre_mask = Lambda(extract_and_duplicate, arguments = {'reps': some_number,'batch_size': batch_size, 'sample_size': sample_size})(input)
mask = TimeDistributed(Dense(m, activation = 'tanh'))(out)
out = Multiply()([pre_mask,mask])
model = Model(input, out)
```

When I load the model with the following line, I get a SIGSEGV signal.

```
load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'estimated_accuracy': estimated_accuracy, 'extract_and_duplicate': extract_and_duplicate})
```

I single-stepped the load_model method and found that it fails with SIGSEGV when loading the Lambda layer.
When I remove the Lambda layer, loading the model works.
Am I doing something wrong or am I stepping on a keras/tensorflow bug?

Can you provide a solution or steps to investigate?
Thanks

Comment: You probably need `some_number`, `batch_size`, `sample_size`, `reps`, everything in `custom_objects`.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to @DanielMöller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass everything necessary to create the lambda layer to `custom_objects`. Otherwise Keras will not know what those variable names mean.

So, add `some_number`, `batch_size`, `sample_size`, `reps` and everything else necessary to build the lambda layer entirely into `custom_objects`.

Comment: I also had to pass `Concatenate` into `custom_objects`. Worked fine. Thanks.